# Mario Party 2 Online; How does it work?

Tags: emulation, mario-party-2

A youtuber I follow has started playing Mario Party 2 online. How does it work? What software do you have to use for it to work?

Comment: Perhaps the  project 64 emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adapted from Elbedhar on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/ifzgv/ysk_how_to_play_super_smash_bros_and_other_n64/)

> 1. Get the project64k emulator. Three places to get it are [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?3fq9adq06mrxf4q),
>      [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/421081014/Project64k_0_13.rar), and
>      [here](http://www.emulation64.com/files/info/203/). Make sure it is
>      project64**k**, not project64. The first two links come with some
>      better plugins so only try the 3rd link if the first two don't work
>      for some reason.
> 2. Get the Mario Party 2 ROM, or the ROM of any other game you want to play online. You're on your own for finding this.
> 3. [Optional] Get a kaillera client. The project64k download already comes with one (kailleraclient.dll). Different versions have different
>      features, so if you ever want to change to another one, put it in your
>      project64k folder and call it kailleraclient.dll. You can get a really
>      good one, with p2p functionality (for less lag), here:
>      http://www.smashboards.com/showthread.php?t=275895
> 4. Configure project64k. Go to file -> Choose ROM directory and pick the folder that you save your games in so pj64k can locate your games.
>      Configure controls and audio / video settings in the Options menu.
>      **DO NOT use full screen for online play!** Make sure you can get the game working fine OFFLINE before attempting to play online.
> 5. [Optional] I'm able to play with the keyboard just fine for most games, but if you have trouble with that, you should set up a
>      controller. If you use a controller, go to Options -> Configure and
>      pick the N-Rage input plugin. For Xbox 360 controllers, you can just
>      plug in with a USB. if you want to use the actual N64 controller, look
>      for the Mayflash USB adapter on Amazon. It's something like $15 and
>      works fine for me. You can use Playstation controllers too but I don't
>      have experience with them.
> 6. To actually get online, go to File -> Start Netplay. Type in a username and then search for servers in the master list or enter an IP
>      manually.
>
> When you play online, [your] connection type (LAN, Excellent, Good, etc.) must match that of your opponents. Don't pay attention to what the connection types
>   actually mean and use the LAN setting unless your opponents are using
>   something else.

Comment: Interesting - have you tried this yourself by chance?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein Yes. I used to play Smash 64 online with Project 64k a few years back. It's a bit janky, but when it works it works pretty well.

Comment: Wow that's crazy, I had no idea! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can play old game on Romstation which enable you to emulate the fact that you and your friends are on the same computer (VPN).
So with that you can play to all the coop old games but online.